# HTML canvas allow user to load image from file

Tags: javascript, jquery, p5.js

I'm trying to make a feature on my canvas where the user clicks a load button that allows them to load an image from any file on their computer, and load the image in to fill the canvas. I've included what I have so far below:

```
function loadTool() {
  var img;
  this.name = "loadTool";
  this.icon = "assets/loadButton.png";
  img = loadImage("assets/star.png");

  this.draw = function() {
    background(img, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

I'm using the p5.js library. Rather than manually loading an image from loadImage, I'd like to allow the user to choose their own image saved on their computer, and fill the canvas with the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `createFileInput()` function provided by the P5.dom helper library.

From [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createFileInput):

```
var input; 
var img; 

function setup() { 
  input = createFileInput(handleFile); 
  input.position(0, 0); 
} 

function draw() { 
  if (img) { 
    image(img, 0, 0, width, height); 
  } 
} 

function handleFile(file) { 
  print(file); 
  if (file.type === 'image') { 
    img = createImg(file.data); 
    img.hide(); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Do you have a JSfiddle available for this? I'd like to change it around without implementing it yet

Comment: @Fuzzer You can copy and paste this directly into the P5.js web editor.